# JasperReport Error evaluating expression: Source text : new java.lang.Integer(1)

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using JasperSoft Studio 5.1.0 for creating my report. This is library I used so far

- commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar commons-collections.jar
  commons-digester-1.7.jar commons-javaflow-20060411.jar
  commons-logging-1.1.3.jar groovy-all-1.7.5.jar itext-2.1.7.jar
  jasperreports-5.1.0.jar

I'm trying using parameter and it's not showing any error when I see the preview on JasperSoft Studio, but when I try to print from my Java program it's show an error like this:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :
>   Source text : new java.lang.Integer(1)

the code I use on my program for action performed is like this

```
try
{
   String NamaFile = "src/Laporan Penawaran.jasper";
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   Connection konek = Koneksi.getKoneksi();
   HashMap hash = new HashMap();
   hash.put("param1",no_tender.getText());

   File file = new File(NamaFile);
   JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(file.getPath());
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, hash,konek);
   JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
} catch(Exception ex) {
   System.out.println(ex);
}
```

I just wondering maybe my jasper file is error, but when I try to erase all field and using only static text the error still exist. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You should post the *jrxml* file

Answer (score 1):

well I'm just trying to update groovy-all to version 2. And after that there's no problem at all and work smoothly :)

note: make sure you are using a specific version for each library, somehow the new one it's not always match for your report

Answer (score 0):

FIX for me:
i changed type of fields from java.math.BigInteger to java.math.BigDecimal

Answer (score -1):

**Below is whole stack trace by which I was able to identify the issue.**

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
    Source text : new java.lang.Integer(1)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:782)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:331)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:384)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:358)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBandNoOverflow(JRVerticalFiller.java:458)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:502)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:284)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:932)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:651)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
    Source text : new java.lang.Integer(1)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluateEstimated(JREvaluator.java:308)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluateEstimated(JRCalculator.java:582)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.estimateVariables(JRCalculator.java:181)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1234)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1208)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1577)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:149)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/BytecodeInterface8
    at ReconciliationDetail_UnclearedTxn_ChecksAndPayments_Count_1450338812203_279237.evaluateEstimated(calculator_ReconciliationDetail_UnclearedTxn_ChecksAndPayments_Count_1450338812203_279237:272)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluateEstimated(JREvaluator.java:295)
    ... 14 more
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.BytecodeInterface8**
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

**FIX Worked for me**

- I have updated all reports/subreports language property from `"groovy"` to `"Java"` and it's fixed .
- Though it looks like workaround I suggest to update library which will include the missing class in `jasperreports-5.1.2.jar`.

Comment: The `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.BytecodeInterface8` is not in the jasperreport jar, but in the groovy jar (included in jasper report distribution folder lib), this jar needs to be in classpath if you are using language="groovy"

Comment: Thanks @PetterFriberg for noticing I missed to mention my further findings. Actually it uses groovy-all-1.7.5.jar in our application which does not contain the class BytecodeInterface8 [http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/1.7.5]

Comment: Updating groovy-all version 2 would work as mentioned by @kripton-haz.